# Error log on XAMPP mySQL file, mySQL shut down unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm using XAMPP server and mySQL just stop working here the error log:

[image: Showing error when Im start mySql]

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-03-05  9:41:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-03-05  9:41:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-03-05  9:41:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-03-05  9:41:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-03-05  9:41:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-03-05  9:41:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-03-05  9:41:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-03-05  9:41:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2021-03-05  9:41:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.`enter code here`
2021-03-05  9:41:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-03-05  9:41:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-03-05  9:41:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-03-05  9:41:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-03-05  9:41:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-03-05  9:41:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 170
2021-03-05  9:41:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-03-05  9:41:54 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-03-05  9:41:54 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-03-05  9:41:54 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2021-03-05  9:41:54 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-03-05  9:41:54 0 [ERROR] Aborting
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 300306; transaction id 170
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210305  9:42:10
2021-03-05  9:42:10 0 [ERROR] Aborting
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 300315; transaction id 170
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-03-05  9:46:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210305  9:46:40
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-03-05  9:49:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-03-05  9:49:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-03-05  9:49:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-03-05  9:49:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-03-05  9:49:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-03-05  9:49:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-03-05  9:49:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-03-05  9:49:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300647
2021-03-05  9:49:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-03-05  9:49:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-03-05  9:49:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-03-05  9:49:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-03-05  9:49:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-03-05  9:49:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-03-05  9:49:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 300656; transaction id 193
2021-03-05  9:49:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-03-05  9:49:59 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-03-05  9:49:59 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-03-05  9:49:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210305  9:49:59
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300665
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 300674; transaction id 193
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-03-05  9:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210305  9:55:51
```

I'm using port 3309 to for mySQL. I already used the port 3309 before encountering this problem. I do not understand the error log and how to find the issue.

I'm using port 3309 to for mySQL. I already used the port 3309 before encountering this problem. I do not understand the error log and how to find the issue.

I'm using port 3309 to for mySQL. I already used the port 3309 before encountering this problem. I do not understand the error log and how to find the issue.

I have tried to use find PID of MySQL but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

it's not the same, but i had a similar problem.

[this solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/271429) helped me and i think it's somewhat general solution, or rather solution for more problems with mysql in xampp.